# How to get information with Track like Xml in json using exiftool

Tags: json, xml, metadata, exiftool

I am trying to get metadata of a video using exiftool but data coming from exiftool is different for both `xml` and `json`

using this command:

```
exiftool -ee -G3 -api LargeFileSupport=1 -X filename.mp4
```

i get output like this for xml:

```
<Track1:GPSDateTime>2020:19:24 03:12:05.456</Track1:GPSDateTime>
```

But for json

```
exiftool -ee -G3 -api LargeFileSupport=1 -j filename.mp4
```

i am getting:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "filename.mp4",
  "Doc1:GPSDateTime": "2020:19:24 03:12:05.456",
}]
```

How can i get Tracks in json too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can get it exactly like you want.  From the [`-j` (`-json`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#j-JSONFILE--json)

> …entries with identical JSON names are suppressed…

You can use multiple group numbers to get unique output, i.e. if you use `-G1:3`, you will get `Track1:Doc1:GPSDateTime`, `Track1:Doc2:GPSDateTime`, etc.

Comment: Thanks but, this way i am only getting 1 `GPSDateTime` whereas when i use `-G3` with `-j` or `-X` then i am getting multiple `GPSDateTime`, is it possible to get all the `GPSDateTime` but with `Track1:`?

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Sorry, I was focused on the XML, not the Json.  I do not believe you can get it exactly like you want.  From the [`-j` (`-json`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#j-JSONFILE--json) "entries with identical JSON names are suppressed".  You can use multiple group numbers to get unique output, i.e. `-G1:3` and get `Track1:Doc1:GPSDateTime`, `Track1:Doc2:GPSDateTime`, etc.  Otherwise, I'd suggest going to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/).  The author is very responsive to questions.

Comment: Since I'm not overly familiar with Json files, my quick google searches show that while it is technically allowed to have duplicated key names, it appears to be discouraged. Exiftool just enforces this.  If you need this ability, I'd suggest posting in the [Exiftool Feature Requests](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?board=6.0) forum.